# Matching the first element between two list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have two list of lists and I want to capture only the matches of the first element between these 2 list of lists. More formally, let us say I have 2 list of lists with

```
list1=[['a','b','c'],['e','f','g'],['i','j','k']]
list2=[['a','m','n'],['i','m','k'],['q','r','s']]
```

and I want to implement a function such that `def function(list1,list2)` returns me `[['a','b','c'],['i','j','k']]` as the result since there is a match between first elements in the inner list namely 'a' and 'i'. Please note that it returns the elements from the first list.

Comment: Please format the code of your question correcetly.

Comment: Please show your attempt to solve it and tell us what problems you are having.

Comment: Yeah. I formatted it. Thanks!

Comment: It isn't clear whether the position in the list matters, e.g. would the result be the same if `['i','j','k']` were the *second* element of `list1`?

Comment: The positions don't really matter.

Comment: Suppose several lists in list1 match a single list in list2. Should that list appear in the results only once or should it be added multiple times. Should we make copies of the lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lists are large, indexing via a dictionary can turn this into faster `set` operations

```
>>> d1 = {l[0]:l for l in list1}
>>> d2 = {l[0] for l in list2}
>>> result = [d1[key] for key in (d1.keys() & d2)]
>>> result
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['i', 'j', 'k']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def function(list1, list2):
    return [l1 for l1 in list1 if any(l2[0]==l1[0] for l2 in list2)]

>>> function(list1, list2)
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['i', 'j', 'k']]
```